# How to load parquet files from hadoopish folder

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

If I save data frame this way in Java, ...:

```
df.write().parquet("myTest.parquet");
```

..., then it gets saved in a hadoopish way (a folder with numerous files).

Is it possible to save data frame as a single file? I tried `collect()`, but it does not help.

If it's impossible, then my question is how should I change the Python code for reading Parquet files from hadoopish folder created by `df.write().parquet("myTest.parquet")`:

```
load_df = sqlContext.read.parquet("myTest.parquet").where('field1="aaa"').select('field2', 'field3').coalesce(64)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark writes your files in a directory, this files in numerous as you say and if the writing operation success it saves another empty file called `_SUCCESS`

I'm coming from scala but I do believe that there's a similar way in python

Save and read your files in `parquet` or `json` or whatever format you want is straightforward :

```
df.write.parquet("path")
loaddf = spark.read.parquet("path")
```

> I tried collect(), but it does not help.

Talking about `collect`, it is not a good practice to use it in such operations because it returns your data to driver so you will lose the parallel computation benefits, and it will cause an `OutOfMemoryException` if the data can't fit in the memory

> Is it possible to save data frame as a single file?

You really don't need to do that in major cases, if so, use the `repartition(1)` method on your `Dataframe` before saving it

Hope it helps, Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to save data frame as a single file?

Yes, but you should not as you may put too much pressure on a single JVM that can lead not only to performance degradation but also to JVM termination and hence the entire Spark application failure.

So, yes, it's possible and you should `repartition(1)` to have a single partition:

> **repartition(numPartitions: Int): Dataset[T]** Returns a new Dataset that has exactly numPartitions partitions.

---

> how should I change the Python code for reading Parquet files from hadoopish folder

Loading the dataset from as you called it a "hadoopish" folder is to not be concerned with the internal structure at all, and consider it a single file (that is a directory under the covers).

That's an **internal representation** of how the files is stored and does not impact the code to load it.